# Angular Js elements not rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, github-api

I am working with Angular JS, HTML 5 and GitHub API. I am trying to get user data of GitHub by making API calls and display it in the form of a table with user ID user name and Avatar of the github user, the program should also be able to sort the program based on UserID and Username. the problem which i am facing is, the data-binding elements of Angular JS, which are supposed to be populated with the dynamic values are not working properly, instead the data-binding expressions are showing up. i tried jacking up with different versions of the Angular JS but none of the versions work, i believe there is something wrong with the placement of the code.the code samples can be seen at

[MyGitHubPage](https://github.com/iamSampath/ContactsApp/blob/master/Angular.html)

Comment: Can you please fix your indentation next time..?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: I made some English changes so we can understand the question better.

Comment: Ryan your changes are helpful

Comment: ᴉʞuǝ i made some changes to the text i hope this definition of the problem is enough!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a pull request with solutions.

https://github.com/iamSampath/ContactsApp/pull/1

You forgot the ng-app, ng-controller, load angular before your angular code ...

Btw, keep you code clean with right indentation.

Comment: perfect solution for the question, code works perfectly

Comment: Henri i am using brackets